# Synchronize Material UI switches with MaterialTable columns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-binding

I cannot get my grid to re-render after changing the `hidden` state of a column. I thought modifying the `columns` would cause the grid to be re-rendered since it is a bound attribute.

Here is an interactive example hosted at [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-table-column-toggle-0w71h).

### index.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

### App.js

```
import React from "react";
import SuperTable from "./components/SuperTable";

const data = [
  { id: 1, type: "Developer", name: "Bob", age: 21 },
  { id: 2, type: "Developer", name: "Mary", age: 28 },
  { id: 3, type: "Manager", name: "Steve", age: 42 }
];

const columns = [
  {
    field: "id",
    title: "ID",
    searchable: true,
    hidden: true
  },
  {
    field: "name",
    title: "Name",
    searchable: true
  },
  {
    field: "age",
    title: "Age",
    searchable: true
  },
  {
    field: "type",
    title: "Type",
    searchable: true
  }
];

const App = () => {
  return <SuperTable data={data} columns={columns} />;
};

export default App;
```

### SuperTable.jsx

```
import MaterialTable from "material-table";
import React, { forwardRef } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import ArrowDownward from "@material-ui/icons/ArrowDownward";
import ChevronLeft from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft";
import ChevronRight from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import ClearIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Clear";
import FirstPage from "@material-ui/icons/FirstPage";
import LastPage from "@material-ui/icons/LastPage";
import Search from "@material-ui/icons/Search";
import ColumnToggler from "./ColumnToggler";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  wrapper: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  widget: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    flex: 0.5
  }
}));

const tableIcons = {
  ResetSearch: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ClearIcon {...props} ref={ref} />),
  FirstPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FirstPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
  LastPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <LastPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
  NextPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
  PreviousPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <ChevronLeft {...props} ref={ref} />
  )),
  Search: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Search {...props} ref={ref} />),
  SortArrow: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ArrowDownward {...props} ref={ref} />)
};

const SuperTable = (props) => {
  const { data, columns, ...rest } = props;

  const classes = useStyles();

  const onToggle = (columnField, show) => {
    const foundColumn = columns.find((col) => col.field === columnField);
    if (foundColumn) {
      foundColumn.hidden = show;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.wrapper}>
      <MaterialTable
        style={{
          position: "unset",
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          flex: 1
        }}
        title={null}
        data={data}
        columns={columns}
        icons={tableIcons}
        pageSize={5}
        {...rest}
      />
      <div className={classes.widget}>
        <ColumnToggler onChange={onToggle} columns={columns} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

SuperTable.propTypes = {
  ...MaterialTable.propTypes
};

export default SuperTable;
```

### ColumnToggler.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Container, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import ColumnToggleSwitch from "./ColumnToggleSwitch";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 200
  }
}));

const ColumnToggler = (props) => {
  const { columns, onChange } = props;

  const classes = useStyles();

  const toggleChecked = (field, show) => {
    onChange(field, show);
  };

  console.log("Updated toggler...");

  return (
    <Container className={classes.formControl}>
      <Typography>Toggle Columns</Typography>
      {columns.map((column) => (
        <ColumnToggleSwitch column={column} onChange={toggleChecked} />
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
};

ColumnToggler.propTypes = {
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default ColumnToggler;
```

### ColumnToggleSwitch.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { FormControlLabel, FormGroup, Switch } from "@material-ui/core";

const ColumnToggleSwitch = (props) => {
  const {
    column: { field, hidden, title },
    onChange
  } = props;
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(hidden == null || !hidden);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setChecked(newValue);
    onChange(event.currentTarget.name, newValue);
  };

  return (
    <FormGroup>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={
          <Switch
            key={field}
            name={field}
            checked={checked}
            onChange={handleChange}
            color="primary"
            inputProps={{ "aria-label": "primary checkbox" }}
            size="small"
          />
        }
        label={title || field}
      />
    </FormGroup>
  );
};

ColumnToggleSwitch.propTypes = {
  column: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default ColumnToggleSwitch;
```

### package.json

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.11.2",
    "material-table": "1.69.2",
    "react": "17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is in React props are immutable. If you modify a prop in your component, the value will not guarantee a re-render.

You're mutating your `columns` prop in your `SuperTable` component and that cannot work properly.

The solution is to define the columns as a constant, import it and set it as the initial state of your `columns` state. `columns` is a constant anyway and it doesn't have to be sent as a prop.

`components/columns.js`:

```
// define columns and export it
```

`SuperTable.jsx`:

```
import initialColumns from './columns';

...
const [columns, setColumns] = useState(initialColumns);
```

States are also immutable, so you shouldn't do:

```
foundColumn.hidden = show;
```

but instead should do:

```
const newColumns = ....;
setColumns(newColumns);
```

Comment: I noticed that if I try to unhide a hidden column, an error is thrown in the console. I realized that the column data for the hidden column has no assigned calculated width. I just fabricated my own widths and it works. Is this the best way to go about this? See my updated (working) example. Also, the columns are going to end up being dynamic, so a constant won't work... [Material UI Table Column Toggle 2.0](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-table-column-toggle-20-1yxku?file=/src/components/SuperTable.jsx)